# How to add bundle product to cart using Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory

Tags: magento2, addtocart, shopping-cart, bundled-product, quoteitem

I want to add bundle products to the cart using `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory`. I have tried the below code and it is working fine.

```
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem */
    $quoteItem = $this->itemFactory->create();
    $quoteItem->setPrice(123.33);
    $quoteItem->setRowTotal($quoteProduct->getPrice());
    $quoteItem->setProductType($quoteProduct->getTypeId());
    $quoteItem->setOriginalPrice(123.33);
    $quoteItem->setCustomPrice(123.33);
    $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(123.33);
    $quoteItem->setQtyOrdered(1);
    $quoteItem->setQty(1);
    $quoteItem->setProduct($quoteProduct);
    $quote->addItem($quoteItem);
    $quote->save();
```

Reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324605/47715

I have used this code to show the same product in the quote as a separate item.

Please help me to fix this

Comment: the code is to just added item to the cart. is that working in your case, right?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes it is working. Now I need to add bundle product.